# How can we restrict deactivated users via Auth::check in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

HI, I have implemented the laravel login module using the laravel authentication. I authenticated the user using the Auth::check and sending the user_name, password in the Auth::attempt method. And I have status column in the users table.

How can I restrict Auth::check to validate the users with status 1 only?

Comment: Thank you Mauricio Trajano. I'll definitely look into custom authentication. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just make the status field one of the confirmations. You can do this:

```
$credentials = array(
        'username' => $input['email'],
        'password' => $input['password'],
        'status' => 1
    );

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) 
    {
        // User status is 1 and password was correct
    }
```

If you want to specifically tell the user they are not active - you can follow it up with this:

```
    if (Auth::validate(['username' => $input['email'], 'password' => $input['password'], 'status' => 0]))
    {
        return echo ('you are not active');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks "The Shift Exchange", your answer worked for me.

Comment: what if user password is wrong ?! both cases will show 'you are not active'

Comment: @alex - no it wont - because the password is wrong - so Auth::validate will return false.

Answer (score 2):

You can add additional conditions to the Auth::attempt method

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'status' => 1)))
{
    //user is logged in (email and password matched, status is 1)
}
```

Comment: Thanks MaGnetas for your answer. It really helped me. But "The Shift Exchange" answer is more elaborated one, so I checked that as my answer.